# not able to render page by loading example projects

Tags: training-certification

I have problem going through 9.3 training courses developer training album 3, not sure it's because I've loaded same project multiple times because it has (album1,2,3,4,5) and when I click the button
Experience Editor I got following errors

```
Error Rendering View: /Views/ClothingCo/Layouts/default.cshtml: Error while rendering view: '/Views/ClothingCo/Layouts/default.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
Inner Exception: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\50e4fe1f\eb23ebb4\App_Web_default.cshtml.25717ab2.fphauiv6.0.cs(39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BasicCompany' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

Comment: I’m getting the same errors
Trying to use the experience editor with blog pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the same error after changing templates on my home page from the Sample Layout to a layout that I had created.

In the end I resolved the error by commenting out the following from \ClothingCompany\src\ClothingCompany.Web\Views\web.config:

`<add namespace="BasicCompany.Foundation.FieldRendering" />`

Comment: In my case this namespace reference doesn't exist in that web.config, yet that view is still being built with the `using BasicCompany.Foundation.FieldRendering;` reference, and still fails.